# React Native Geolocation average speed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, geolocation

I have a react native app where I track the user's location and display his movement on a map. My goal is to display the user's average speed that he/she is traveling with.

Now in the React Native's geolocation watchPosition's response is a speed parameter, this is only from the last known coordinates to the new coordinates.

response:

```
{
  coords: {
    accuracy: 5,
    altitude: 0,
    altitudeAccuracy: -1,
    heading: 108.43,
    latitude: 38.333034435,
    longitude: -122.04128193
    speed: 6.5
  }
  timestamp: 1465109890871.304
}
```

Is there a way to get the average speed over the whole trajectory? Or how can I calculate this speed?

It sounds absurd and not very performant to keep all the "speed" values in an array and then devide it by the amount of values in the array.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I did the way you explained, store in an array and divide by the amount in the array. Do you know what metric the speed is? (kilometre or metres)

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it using `getCurrentPosition` and `redux` and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106313/regular-average-calculated-accumulatively) formula -

```
  var speedCounter = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
  }, 1000);

  function success(position) {
    ++speedCounter;
    var speed = position.coords.speed < 0 ? 0 : Math.round(position.coords.speed);
    var topSpeed = getState().data.topSpeed;
    var avgSpeed = getState().data.avgSpeed;

    dispatch({
      type: DATA_SPEED,
      speed: speed,
      topSpeed: speed > topSpeed ? speed : topSpeed,
      avgSpeed: Math.round((avgSpeed * (speedCounter - 1) + speed) / speedCounter),
    });
  }
```

I used `getCurrentPosition` because `watchPosition` did not work well for me. But that was long time ago. Not sure how accurate `watchPosition` is, in latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

offering another solution to the good one of @vinayr
If accuracy not good enough, you might have GPS lat/longitude but not speed (in my case I have speed=-2) so you might need something else than just speed.

Whenever you get some new coordinates, you calculate distance to previous location using the calculateDistance method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23448821/1611358 or this npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/haversine .

Then you have 2 options to calculate avg speed:

- whenever speed is negative, you calculate it (with method above + duration between two coordinates: use timestamp), and you update your avg Speed using nb of measures + last avg speed + new position speed (as done by @vinayr)
- you append distance and duration in two variables totalDistance and totalDuration, your avg speed is always totalDistance/totalDuration (what I'm doing)